# What's the complex conjugate of a spacetime interval?

Tags: special-relativity

In SR, one of 2 ways to represent elapsed time in the Minkowski metric is *ict.* It is the vertical axis and is purely imaginary.

Intervals appear as line segments in 4D complex space, on the upper half of the complex plane.

What is the meaning of the corresponding points on the *lower* half of the complex plane?

Comment: I'm not sure what special meaning you seem to assign here to positive/negative time - what events are in the "upper half" depends on your choice of $t=0$, no?

Comment: If t=0 is the present, then t<0 is the past WRT t=0 and t>0 is the future WRT t=0. So lower half plane past, upper half plane future. But in modern presentation of SR the imaginary coordinate ict is no longer used, because it makes things complex what is not necessary.

Comment: > what special meaning you seem to assign here to positive/negative time
  ---  
I have never talked about positive/negative time.  I've never even heard of it.

Comment: the "upper complex plane" and "lower complex plane" correspond to positive and negative $t$, do they not? If that's not what you mean, you should edit your question to make that clearer.

Comment: How you have never heard of positive/negative time? Set your clock at $t=0$ now, anything that happened before is assigned a negative value of $t$ and everthing that happens after is assigned a positive value of $t$. This does not even have anything to do with relativity.

Answer (score 2):

The coordinate $t$ can be both positive and negative.  You fix some time that you call "time $t=0$" and everything before that time has a negative value. (Think of a rocket launch.  They choose $t=0$ to be the time of engine ignition or lift-off, and then you have the almost cliche countdown sequence "t minus 60 seconds, ...".  That "minus" means a time *before* ignition.)

Most physicists don't use this "$ict$" construct anymore, but, if you do, taking the complex conjugate just gives you an event in spacetime that has the same spatial coordinates and occurs as much before your "$t=0$ time" as the original event occurred after that same $t=0$. (Or if you started with a time $t<0$, then it's the opposite - the complex conjugate is in the future relative to your original event.)

Comment: Great, thanx!  I use the other (non-ict) equation too. This was interesting because I'm trying to understand the physical meaning of i.

Answer (score 0):

Because the terms in an interval are squared, it makes no fundamental difference. For some interval $s$,

$$s^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+(ict)^2$$

Positive or negative spatial $x, y, z$ coordinates are just front-back, left-right, up-down directions. Similarly, positive or negative temporal $t$  coordinates are just past-future times.

A time cone is an zero interval and extends in both past and future.